# Is it possible to control an application while using another application?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I'm writing a command-line music player which I want to be able to control without currently being on the terminal. That way I could be using Chrome or reading a pdf, and could control (pause, next etc) the music player without having to switch to the terminal.

Is there any Python library (in-built or otherwise) which could allow me to do this?

Comment: Your best bet might be running the script in the background, and perhaps setting keyboard shortcuts equal to scripts that would interact with the first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use messages since you don't want to change windows. The message can be sent using your keyboard's media keys or using some widget (This document can be a pointer to start searching [NotifyOSD](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD)), the keyboard alternative is probably easier to get started since it is just a file that says "when this key is pressed execute this script", use [xmodmap](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap) to configure the keys.

For the messages I see two alternatives,

#### First alternative:

Use [dbus](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/doc/tutorial.html) in your application to receive messages.

#### Second alternative:

Create a socket and receive messages from it, [this is a good strategy for mpd](https://superuser.com/questions/61949/can-i-use-my-media-keys-to-control-mpd) and will be for you as well.